# apt-get update error after dpkg --add-architecture i386

Tags: apt

I have recently put Chrubuntu on my HP chromebook 11 (it's ARM). I currently have Xubuntu-desktop lts, checking version gives Ubuntu 14.04. I'm following this tutorial: [install kingsoft office ubuntu 14.04](http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/08/install-kingsoft-office-linux-ubuntu-14-04/)

After:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

I wrote:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

but always get this:

```
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80] W: Failed to fetch htt=p://ppa.launchpad.net/iaz/battery-status/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-armhf/Packages 404  Not Found    
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/iaz/battery-status/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages 404  Not Found    
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]    
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]    
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty/universe/binary-i386/Packages 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]    
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]    
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]    
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]    
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]    
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]    
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-i386/Packages 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]    
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]    
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]    
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]    
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've tried to update the sources.list but that didn't help, it replaced ports.ubuntu with us.archive.ubuntu but same errors.

Answer (score 1):

It was not even supposed to work. `ports.ubuntu.com` does not contain i386 packages. You have to manually edit `/etc/apt/sources.conf` and add proper package mirror there.